# Why are random characters (e, ?, `, ... ) appearing in my text field (attribute table) of the shapefile in QGIS 3.0?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, qgis-3

I have a shapefile that I have created which has a few features (about 10) and I have input attribute information for each feature and each attribute (set to text).

For example, one of my fields is called `Acer negundo` (no accents or other odd fonts). Sometimes, the unicode replacement character � appears beside the information in the fields with attribute information and also in the fields with no attribute information.

It is further frustrating because I have a filter (`is not NULL`) to only show features with attribute information, and the filter doesn't work when the random characters appear.

I've tried changing the coding from `system` to `UTF-8` without any helpful changes.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the shapefiles for testing?

Comment: Unfortunately the shapefiles are part of a projet for a client that is confidential :(

Comment: The problem must be related to the codepage that is used for writing the .dbf file. Unfortunately without test data is is very hard to help you. Can't you generate a shapefile with fake data that shows the same issue?